# DataFrame: from string dictionnary in one columns to floats in two column {'latitude': '34.04', 'longitude': '-118.24'}

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geolocation, folium

I have a pandas DataFrame `df` with a column `latlng`.
The rows in this column have the format

`{'latitude': '34.041005', 'longitude': '-118.249569'}`.

In order to be able to add markers to a map (using folium librairie), I would like to create two columns `'latitude'` and `longitude` which in this example would contain respectively `34.041005` and `-118.249569`.

---

**EDIT:**
Managed to have it working with this first step:
df['latlng'] = df['latlng'].map(eval)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) to avoid `apply` which is costly:

```
In [684]: df_out = pd.json_normalize(df.latlong)
In [686]: df_out
Out[686]: 
    latitude    longitude
0  34.041005  -118.249569
1  30.041005  -120.249569
```

Then you can concat these columns back to `df` like below:

```
pd.concat([df.drop('latlong', axis=1), df_out], axis=1)
```

Comment: ```pd.json_normalize(df.latlong)``` returns ```AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'```

Comment: @DeepNet It should work. Can you please share a sample of your data frame where you are trying to run this?

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
df['latitude']=[i['latitude'] for i in eval(df['latlong'])]
df['longtitude']=[i['longtitude'] for i in eval(df['longtitude'])]
```

Comment: ```TypeError: string indices must be integers```

Comment: I guess this is because your latlong column is a string not a dict. I added eval in the code, please check again

Comment: Yes, thanks you, I've made an edit to my original post

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job for you:

```
df['blatlong'].apply(pd.Series)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however it does not split the dictionnary into two columns names  ```'latitude'``` and ```'longitude'```, it simply creates a pandas Series...

Comment: See edit in original post

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(df['latlng'].values.tolist(), index=df.index)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however it does not split the dictionnary into two columns names  ```'latitude'``` and ```'longitude'```, it simply creates a pandas Series...

Comment: See edit in original post